# puppeteer Error: No node found for selector: .olp-text-box

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the number of sellers (which are selling only **NEW** items) on the Amazon product page using puppeteer.

for some reason, I'm getting error in the first button '.olp-text-box'.
Any ideas?

here is my code

```
    const pupUrl = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/' + req.body.asinIdInput;

  async function configureBrowser(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(pupUrl , {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
    await page.click('.olp-text-box');
    await page.click('#aod-filter-string');
    await page.click('.a-size-base.a-color-base')
    return page;
  }
  
  async function checkSellers(page){
    await page.reload();
    let html = await page.evaluate(()=> document.body.innerHTML);
  
    $('#aod-filter-offer-count-string',html).each(function(){ 
      var numberOfSellers = $(this).text();
      console.log(numberOfSellers);
    });
  }
  
  
  async function monitor(){
    let page = await configureBrowser();
    await checkSellers(page);
  }
  
  monitor();
```

Comment: have you tried `page.waitForSelector()` ?

Comment: What's the value of `req.body.asinIdInput`? This design leaks memory; there's no way to close the `browser` resource.

Comment: @AzizaKasenova I'm not familiar with page.waitForSelector() can you give me some input? tnx

Comment: @ggorlen well req.body.asinIdInput in an input which the user is writing the relevant Asin (amazon product id) he wants to get data of. 
its basically a form that triggers a POST route for the scraping.

Comment: `page.waitForSelector` is a function which waits for a given selector and triggers a callback: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options

Comment: I realize that it's user input -- that's precisely the issue. What sort of value might it take? The problem is, without having this value I have no idea which page you're scraping, what the behavior of its selectors are, what they're called, etc, so I can't answer your question. As is, it's pure guesswork as to why the code fails. If you could share a sample value for this, hard code the user input, I can then run the code and potentially offer help. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @ggorlen , the input is a basic form input that the user inserts an amazon product id [Asin] for example B08N2FRMPN.  the name attribute of that input is "asinIdInput". 
one of the ways to go to the amazon product page is- amazon.com/dp/[Relevant Asin]
This is why I have created the URL based on the Asin the user insert ('https://www.amazon.com/dp/' + req.body.asinIdInput;)

from that point, all I'm trying to achieve is the number of sellers selling NEW products - it's clicking on two buttons and filtering to NEW. then you can see these exact data. 
I hope this is understood. Thanks